# How do I get a Type[] with arguments from a MethodCallExpression?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, arguments

I'm reflecting over a class (in a unit test of said class) to make sure its members have all the required attributes. To do so, I've constructed a couple of helpers, that take an `Expression` as an argument. I do some checks for it, and take slightly different actions depending on what type of `Expression` it is, but it's basically the same.

Now, **my problem is** that I have several methods with the same name (but different signatures), and the following code throws an `AmbiguousMatchException`:

```
// TOnType is a type argument for the type where the method is declared
// mce is the MethodCallExpression
var m = typeof(TOnType).GetMethod(mce.Method.Name);
```

Now, if I could add an array of `Type[]` with the types of the arguments to this method as a second parameter to `.GetMethod()`, the problem would be solved.

**But how do I find this `Type[]` array that I need?**

I have cast the `Expression<Func<...>>` to an `Expression`, and then to a `MethodCallExpression`, and in this method the contents of `<...>` is not known.

Comment: I am confused by the question. You have a MethodCallExpression in hand, yes?  Why not just look at the method info in the method call expression? Doesn't that have everything you need?  Can you clarify the question?  Some sample code might help.

Comment: I do not get it. Perhaps you could explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using reflection to find the `MethodInfo` ? You already have it from the `MethodCallExpression`...

Just do this :

```
var m = mce.Method;
```